# "Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed" after launching a browser and returning to the app

Tags: ios, swiftui, swift-data

I have a SwiftUI (document-based) app using Swift Data, running on an iPhone 13 with iOS 17.2. In one of the Views, I have

```
@Environment(\.openURL) private var openURL

var body: some View {
  VStack {
      Button("Open Browser") {
        openURL(URL(string: "https://some.url")!)
      }
  }
  .navigationTitle("Settings")
}
```

When clicking the button, the browser launches normally. However, when returning to the app using the "back" navigation link on the top left, the app first logs

```
Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.
```

Then, in a collection getter of one the Swift Data @Model-s, supposed to get a collection that is read when the app's GUI is rendered, the application crashes, saying

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unable to get value - no backing Managed Object
```

The whole thing looks to me as if, when switching back from the browser to my app, the entire GUI were rendered from a non-main thread (which, as this thread also has no ModelContainer und ModelContext, cannot load the SwiftData models).

Unfortunately, the call stack of this Fatal Error above is not of much help - the generated SwiftData getter is the only Swift code I see there, up the stack are just locations within the compiled assembly code.

Why is this happening?

**Update 31.01.2024**:

This looks like an OS bug to me that is specific to the iPhone. The problem does not occur on either the simulator or an iPad Air Gen 5 (running iPadOS 17.2).

Apple's [WWDC23 SwiftUI Document Based App Sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Building-a-document-based-app-using-SwiftData) also produces this behaviour. I have removed the part of the question stating that this does not occur when manually putting the app to the background. In fact it does, it is just not fully deterministic.

So what you need to reproduce this is a document based app, whose main view includes a SwiftData query. After some more debugging, here is what seems to happen:

- After putting the app to the background, SwiftUI reloads the main view (calls body()). This may happen a couple of times. At this stage, the Swift Data query still returns a result.
- When re-opening the app from the background, SwiftUI reloads the main view (calls body()) again in an infinite loop. In the first few iterations of this loop, the Swift Data query still returns a result, but after a while, it starts returning an empty array (and `$backingData.managedObject` is nil). This is where the errors are produced.

According to the debugger, this all happens on the main thread.

Comment: I don’t know the specifics of your code, but is the openURL function asynchronous and not annotated with @MainActor? Could you please upload the full code of openURL()?

Comment: I am assuming you problem is related to Application comming from background maybe some operation are being done related to Core Data there?

Comment: @windowcow openURL is a Swift UI builtin, injected through the Environment, see here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/openurlaction

Comment: @ReinierMelian I don't have any custom application code tied to the event when the app comes back from the background.